# c# array declaration syntax vs c++ array declaration syntax

Tags: c#, c++, .net

I am basically c++ guy,now learning c#. 
While array declaration I found that c# expects the square brackets after the type unlike c,c++. 
Is there any reason c# language specification is this way?

Comment: I am also a C++ guy, but I must say I find the C array declaration syntax counter-intuitive.

Comment: @juanchopanza ya,i agree,but now used it :)

Comment: In fact the actual type in C++ is also `T[N]` (with the brackets directly after the base type), it's just the declaration that has to be written differently, which is indeed a bit contradictory.

Comment: Does c++ array size can be changed later after declaration ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only good reason I can think of is to make a clear indication of the types of list1 and list2 in this construction:

In C#:

```
int[] list1, list2;
```

list2 is an array of ints.

In C++:

```
int list1[], list2;
```

list2 is an int.

Readability is key here.

Comment: That doesn't compile in C++ though - you need "int list1[], list2".

Answer (score 3):

It's also for consistency (which helps readability).

In a C# variable declaration, the complete type specification is always on the left of the variable name.

In C/C++ sometimes part of the type specification is on the right of the variable name, which is inconsistent.

Comment: Can you give me an example of part of type specification on the right side of =, in C++

Comment: @ZoomIn Sorry, I meant to say "variable name", not "="... I've corrected my post.